# Can I have the same URL, but different dynamic segments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

Is it possible to use the same URL, but with different dynamic segments?

My issue is: I want to be able add object `A` to objects `B` and `C`. So I want to have 2 Rails routes, `A/new/:b_id` AND `A/new/:c_id`. Which I tried.

In my routes.rb:

```
controller :A do
  get 'A/new/:b_id', to: 'A#new', as: :new_b_a
  get 'A/new/:c_id', to: 'A#new', as: :new_c_a 
end
```

Problem is that the value being passed into the new page is always `params[:b_id]`! (I can print out the value from the URL using `params[:b_id]`.)

So it seems like maybe I can't have 2 similar routes with different dynamic segments..? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to accomplish this would be using [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

You always get `:b_id` because Rails matches routes in the order they appear in your file. Since a `B` ID is an integer indistinguishable from a `C` ID, there's no way for it to know if you want one or the other.

But, since you do have `B`s and`C`s already, and perhaps those also need to be created, shown, etc., you can differentiate their paths RESTfully, which is what Rails wants you to do.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :bs do
  resources :as
end

resources :cs do
  resources :as
end
```

This will build you the paths you're creating manually, but turned around a bit:

```
/bs/:b_id/as/new
/cs/:c_id/as/new
```

As you can see, the paths now start with the object type you want to add an `A` too, so Rails can tell them apart. The helper methods generated for this look the same as the ones you're currently defining manually:

```
new_b_a_path(b)
new_c_a_path(c)
```

Both paths will route you to the `AsController`, and then you'll need to look up the correct `B` or `C` based on the parameter present:

```
# AsController#new
@parent = B.find(params[:b_id]) if params[:b_id]
@parent = C.find(params[:c_id]) if params[:c_id]
@a = parent.build_a # Assuming has_one or has_many from B and C to A
```

Rails has spent a long time developing a particular way to do this sort of thing. You can always dive in and do it a different way, but at best you'll be wasting effort, and at worst you'll be fighting the framework. The framework is less compromising and usually wins.

Answer (score 2):

The routing system works by trying to match the current path to each of the registered routes, from top to bottom. The dynamic `:b_id` part means "anything that goes here in the path will be passed as a parameter called `:b_id` to the controller". So making a request to `"A/new/anything"` will always match the first route, and since you renamed the parameter to `:new_b_a`, that's how it's called in the `params` hash.

If you really want to use the same route, you'll need to pass an extra argument specifying the class you want to create the relationship with, though I'd not recommend doing that. It could be something like `get 'A/new/:klass/:id'`, so in the controller you could match the parameter to the desired classes:

```
def new
  case params[:klass]
  when 'B' then # do stuff
  when 'C' then # do stuff
  else raise "Invalid class: #{params[:klass]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Good idea, giving an upvote…but I think @kristjen 's answer is more what rails wants. Thanks for the explanation, though!